# How to hide/remove a field in Magento

Tags: magento

As the title said, I really want to remove a bunch of fields in Magento product page but don't know how. I tried to search on Internet but found no revelance.

What I have to do in this situation? I'm new in Magento!

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I want to remove field in admin panel.

Comment: Could you be more specific what you want to hide and provide more detail on which programming language you are using

Comment: Where you want to hide fields in frontend or in admin panel?

Comment: I want to remove completely fields in admin panel. Description updated.

Answer (score 1):

Start here: [Intro to Layouts](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts)

Once you understand how layout works, look in `your_theme_folder/layout/catalog.xml`. Everything your are interested in is located under `<catalog_product_view>` handle.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The method for removing the field depends on whether the field is a default product attribute such as "SKU" or "name" or a custom attribute such as "length".

If you are removing a custom attribute, you can do so in the Magento admin panel under Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribute Sets by selecting the relevant attribute set and removing the desired field.

I am less certain about removing a core Magento product attribute field, but know the product attribute fields displayed in Catalog->Manage Products-> edit product are added via a php script and not a layout file. The php file for this is app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Setup.php. The specific function is "getDefaultEntities()".